# Will external SSD (via USB 3.0) be faster than HDD when it's running a VMWare?

Tags: hard-drive, usb, ssd, external-hard-drive, vmware

I have read on this site than an external SSD will be faster than an external HDD (in my case I am using USB 3.0). It has been said that the SSD will be particularly faster when accessing many small files. (at least if I've understood it correctly).

But what about the scenario when I have a VMWare image on an external drive. Will the SSD also be much faster then? I am asking because typically the VM-files seem to be about 2GB large, so aren't small files.

Many thanks in advance...

Comment: SSDs are generally faster than HDDs no matter what the file size

Comment: You are mistaken about the access pattern. File size doesn't matter at all. Only how much is read. As such, VMs are no different from real PCs.

Answer (score 0):

A general answer:

An SSD is likely to be faster than HDD independent of how you connect/access it - assuming that the connection itself is faster than or equally fast as the SSD.

So a 5Gbps USB3 connection should allow to retain much of the speed of even a 6Gbps SSD, but maybe not allow it to run at top/possible speed.
But do count in ALL items in the connection; you're probably using some kind of SATA-2-USB conversion also, the cabling, the interfacing circuitry, the driver software, maybe some BIOS settings.